# Help to make a Pick Chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{mark options={mark size=2, line width=3pt}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[height=5cm,width=8cm,scale only axis,
        xlabel= \textbf{Esfuerzo},
        ylabel= \textbf{Impacto},
        ymax = 45,
        ymin = 15,
        legend columns=0,
        xticklabels={Bajo},
        yticklabels={Bajo}]

        \addplot[mark=none, black,very thick, dotted] coordinates {(0,30) (12,30)};
        \addplot[mark=none, black,very thick, dotted] coordinates {(6,00) (06,60)};

        \addplot[only marks, color=red,mark=*] coordinates { (1,31) (2,35) (2.5,20) (4,28) (5,19) (5,40) (7,20) (8,36) (9,35) (10,29) (7,29) (8,56) (9,35) (10,20) (12,24) }; 
        %\addlegendentry{} 
        \node[] at (axis cs: 1,41.5) {Implementar};
        \node[] at (axis cs: 12,41.5) {Desafío};
        \node[] at (axis cs: 0,18) {Posible};
        \node[] at (axis cs: 12,18) {Ignorar};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any suggest for get the labels like the graph below?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! This is not really a fair question to ask: the site is not a do-it-for-me order service, but a community who attempt to help people to do things themselves. Of course, you may get lucky and somebody does your work for you, especially if your target image is cute or interesting (e.g. ducks rather than dots). But you are more likely to get help if you post the code you've got so far and ask about the specific problem you're having drawing the image. The code should be that for a minimal but complete document demonstrating the specific issue you need help with.

Comment: @cfr The OP has added a MWE now.

Comment: @TeXnician I seriously doubt it works. I don't think the OP can have tested it at all! The body of the code is probably good and helpful, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the `figure` and `measuredfigure` environment since `figure` doesn't work by default in `standalone`, and I don't know off hand where `measuredfigure` comes from.

You can give a name to the `axis`, with `name=ax`, and use that to place nodes relative to it.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[height=5cm,width=8cm,scale only axis,
        ymax = 45,
        ymin = 15,
        legend columns=0,
        xticklabels={},
        yticklabels={},
        mark options={ % unless you have multiple tikzpictures/axis, it makes more sense to have this here
          mark size=2,
          line width=3pt
        },
        name=ax  % <-- added
     ]

        \addplot[mark=none, black,very thick, dotted] coordinates {(0,30) (12,30)};
        \addplot[mark=none, black,very thick, dotted] coordinates {(6,00) (06,60)};

        \addplot[only marks, color=red,mark=*] coordinates { (1,31) (2,35) (2.5,20) (4,28) (5,19) (5,40) (7,20) (8,36) (9,35) (10,29) (7,29) (8,56) (9,35) (10,20) (12,24) }; 
        %\addlegendentry{} 
        \node[] at (axis cs: 1,41.5) {Implementar};
        \node[] at (axis cs: 12,41.5) {Desafío};
        \node[] at (axis cs: 0,18) {Posible};
        \node[] at (axis cs: 12,18) {Ignorar};
        \end{axis}

    \node [below left] at (ax.north west) {High};
    \node [left]       at (ax.west)       {Payoff};
    \node [above left] at (ax.south west) {Low};

    \node [below right] at (ax.south west) {Easy};
    \node [below]       at (ax.south)      {Difficulty};
    \node [below left]  at (ax.south east) {Hard};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```